# Sed not working inside bash for loop

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

I want to replace an image path inside all html files recursively in all folders.

```
#!/bin/bash

for image in images/*.png
do

  echo "sed -i .bak -e 's|$image|image2/$image|g' app/www/*.html"
  sed -i .bak -e 's|$image|image2/$image|g' app/www/*.html

done
```

The weird thing is that when I manually execute the command:

```
  sed -i .bak -e 's|images/add.png|image2/add.png|g' app/www/*.html
```

everything works fine and the path is replaces. However inside the for loop this doesn't work while the echo part echoes the same line as mentioned above.

Comment: Based on the answer it could be a duplicate. But was the question itself a duplicate as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use " and not '
Otherwise the $image is not evaluated

Edit: it works in the echo because the ' surrounded string is surrounded by " ;)

Comment: This fixed it thanks!